# JQ - access nested square brackets with fields with no names

Tags: arrays, json, select, jq

trying to access a field in the list array via jq.  The fields doesnt have a name for me to gain access to and extract.  Please assist?

Trying to extract John and Smith.

```
$ cat test.txt
{
    "content": {
        "list": [
            [
                [
                    "name",
                    "John",
                    123
                ],
                [
                    "surname",
                    "Smith",
                    345
                ],
                1
            ]
        ]
    }
}

$ jq -r '.content | {name: ."list"}' test.txt
{
  "name": [
    [
      [
        "name",
        "John",
        123
      ],
      [
        "surname",
        "Smith",
        345
      ],
      1
    ]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something as naive as:

```
$ jq -r '.content.list[][][1]?' test.json
John
Smith
```

Which will extract the second field from the array third nested arrays, and ignore the numeric literal.

Alternative you could manipulate the data before-hand to make it easier to manipulate afterwards:

```
$ jq '.content.list | map(map({ (.[0]): .[1] }?) | add)' 
[
  {
    "name": "John",
    "surname": "Smith"
  }
]
```

Extracting the name(s) would be as simple as just using `| [].name`:

```
$ jq '.content.list | map(map({ (.[0]): .[1] }?) | add) | .[].name'
"John"
```